# Difference between Atom Service and REST Service

Tags: rest, atom-feed

Can somebody explain the difference between an ATOM Service and a REST Service?

ATOM Service format is an XML based data format but wondering how is it different from a REST Service.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

REST is the architectural design and primarily consists of [six constraints](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Constraints).

ATOM is a data trasport format specification built with XML. Any REST service could use an ATOM format, a JSON format, or any other format depending on the design goals.